# How to handle differing .mp4 file types from different sources?

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg, mp4

If I take a .mp4 recorded on my mobile (Samsung S5) and pass it through FFmpeg with the below command, the output file (`fileX.avi`) is a greyscale bitmap uncompressed video file.

- The offset values in `fileX.avi` (output from FFmpeg) to allow me to locate the video frame data are always 5680 bytes for the file header.
- And 62 bytes for the inter frame header.
- The data is uncompressed RGB24 so i can easily calculate the size of a video frame from height x width x 3.

So  my C# application can access the video frames in `fileX.avi` always at these above offsets.
(This works great).

My FFmpeg Command is:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i source.mp4 -b 1150 -r 20.97 -g 120 -an -vf format=gray -f rawvideo -pixfmt gray -s 384x216 -vcodec rawvideo -y fileX.avi
```

However... I recently took an .mp4 file from a different source (produced by Power Director 14 instead of direct from my mobile phone) and used this as the input `source.mp4`.  But now the structure of `fileX.avi` differs as the offset values of 5680 +  62 bytes from the start in `fileX.avi` do not land me at the start of the video data frames.

There seems to be different file formats for .mp4 - and obviously if there are my crude offset approach will not work for them all. I suspected at the time I wrote the code my method was all too easy a solution!

So can anyone advise on the approach I should take now?  Should I check the original .mp4 or the output file (`fileX.avi`) to determine a *"file type"* to which I can determine the different offsets?

At the very least I need to be able to identify the *"type"* of .mp4 file that works so I can declare the type that will work with my software.

Comment: Regarding (1) _"the output is a bitmap uncompressed video file"_ what file type are you outputting? (2) _"The values are always 5680 bytes for the file header"_ so that can't be the MP4 file, what are you talking about?... (3) Try outputting to `.rgb` format in FFmpeg then you can find each frame's byte size by `width x height x 3` (research how to output 24-bit rgb video frames)...

Comment: PS: FFmpeg flags to make 24-bit RGB video `-f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24`

Comment: Sorry I can understand how you were confused a bit from my wording.   The file I am talking about interrogating is the file produced as output from FFMPEG, which by using the command I stated, produces a grey scale 24bpp raw video data file which is exactly what I want.    However it still appears to me that when the .mp4 input is generated from different sources then it will not always be possible to use the same
offset values in the FFMPEG output to access the frame data.

Comment: What I need is an FFMPEG command which will always guarantee to output the same raw video 24bpp format in which I can use the same offsets for stepping into the file and grabbing the video frames for all variations of .mp4 input.

Comment: Is this solved or you still need solution?

Comment: Hi yes I still need a solution.   It's a real show stopper for me and I can't progress a project I am doing until it's solved.

Comment: I've wrote some C# code that displays the individual frames (steps through each frame via click). Your FFmpeg command produces RGB data only, no headers and no inter frame. So now I'm only confused by your `5680` bytes and `62` for keyframe header... Are you adding these extra bytes yourself (after FFmpeg finished, you edit `filex.dat` just to add them)? What info uses five thousand bytes in header?

Comment: Ok I did'nt realise the extensions to the FFmpeg command you suggested meant there was no longer an AVI file generated but just a stream of image frames in a file.  The stream of frames is better for me so we can forget now about the headers i mentioned.  I have also changed the FFmpeg command slightly to be "-pix_fmt gray" as i only need 8bpp and was previously having to strip out the extra 2 bytes per pixel.  The images produced are upside down now - but i can live with that for now.

Comment: However i am arriving now back at the original issue - .mp4's from my mobile work fine.  But if for example I take two .mp4s and append them together using a video edditing utility such as Power Director 14, the resulting .mp4 generated by Power Director 14 will not process correctly through the FFmpeg command.  When i try to use the data file produced the images generated are just a rectangular block of pixels along the bottom of the screen.

Comment: ... this leads me to think that not all .mp4's will work with my application.  I've also tried generating an AVI file from the two .mp4's using power director 14 and then passing that into the FFmpeg command - but the same problem occurs.

Comment: Hold off on this - it may be working now.  I will post back to confirm if fixed.

Comment: This is now working.  The ffmpeg command was not at fault it was my application  not working with portrait videos which was leading me down the wrong path.  Thanks very much for your help VC.one.

Comment: Not sure of the procedure to close down this question now that ts not a problem for me. ?