# How to identify exact type or variation of a .mp4 file

Tags: ffmpeg

Can anyone tell me if there are different variations of mp4 file and if so, how to identify the exact type or variation of a mp4 file?

The reason I need to know this is if I pass an .mp4 through FFMPEG to create an uncompressed grayscale rgb24 avi file, depending on 
where the .mp4 file has been sourced from will produce a different internally structured avi file as output from FFMPEG.   Ie, the file header
and interframe header sizes differ.

The ffmpeg command i am using is:
ffmpeg.exe -i source.mp4 -b 1150 -r 20.97 -g 120 -an -vf format=gray -f rawvideo -pixfmt rgb24 -s 384x216 -vcode rawvideo -y fileX.avi

So far I have identified that .mp4 files generated by my Samsung S5 mobile phone differ from .mp4 files generated by Power Director 14.  So I suspect there are different variations of .mp4 files.

I have written some software which steps into the FFMPEG output .avi file to extract video frames, but it requires fixed offset positions to work so I can only make it work for one variation of .mp4.

Comment: As asked, it's unclear what you mean by variations of MP4 files. What command are you using for AVI generation?

Comment: ffmpeg.exe -i source.mp4 -b 1150 -r 20.97 -g 120 -an -vf format=gray -f rawvideo -pixfmt rgb24 -s 384x216 -vcode rawvideo -y fileX.avi

Comment: The trouble is I can't identify if my question title is correct or its an issue with my FFMPEG command and there are actually no different types of mp4 file.

Comment: There are different types of MP4 files but they won't be relevant to the differences in the output, given your type of command. Run your command with `-report` added and share the report generated, since your command as shown here isn't valid.

Comment: @Mulvya this is related to [**How to handle differing .mp4 file types from different sources?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46284550/how-to-handle-differing-mp4-file-types-from-different-sources).

Comment: @VC.One the weird thing here is that due to `-f rawvideo` in the cmd, the output is a raw stream and not a AVI. So output file should always be very regular.

Comment: This is now working for me.  The ffmpeg command was ok and it was my application not processing portrait video clips correctly which was causing confusion.  Thanks for you help everyone.  Not sure how to close down this queston?